# How do you link a Typekit font inline with css?

Tags: html, css, fonts

On my website i have this code injection bit that i need to use a custom font on.

I have the following code but the font will not render correctly (it should be very bold). You can try it here https://loosethreadsintel.com/fast-frivolous-building-consumer-brands-evolving-accelerating-evaporating/

What am I doing wrong?

```
<style>
      @import url("https://use.typekit.net/fpi7xqf.css");
    </style>
    <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;"> 
        <h1 class="tk-antique-olive-nord" style="color:red;  font-family: 'antique-olive-nord' ; text-shadow: -3px 3px white; text-align: center;"> FAST </h1>
    <h1 class="tk-antique-olive-nord"style="color:red;   font-family: 'antique-olive-nord';text-shadow: -3px 3px white; text-align: center;">OR  </h1>
    <h1 class="tk-antique-olive-nord" style="color:red;   font-family: 'antique-olive-nord';text-shadow: -3px 3px white; text-align: center;"> FRIVOLOUS  </h1> 
    </div>
```

Comment: You have incorrect syntax in your mark-up, maybe this is the reason. Add spaces between classes and styles everywhere: class="tk-antique-olive-nord"style="color:red;

Comment: @Dima thanks. i fixed that but still not working.

Comment: Did you read [Add fonts to your website](https://helpx.adobe.com/typekit/using/add-fonts-website.html) or [Embed codes](https://helpx.adobe.com/typekit/using/embed-codes.html) articles?

Comment: @Alexander yes inline is not covered from what i can tell

Comment: Seems like it's working in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dzhka88/). Is it an environment issue?

Comment: It works for me, too. Do you have other code that surrounds the snippet that you pasted here?

Comment: @trevorp thanks for checking. its really weird because it sometimes works on safari or chrome on desktop or mobile but other times not.